# Android App crash when come back from long idle

Tags: java, android

I'm some what new to Android.  My application crash when user return from long idle.  I have read the Android app life cycle and debug the app. It looks like my app crash at the onCreate method when user come back from long idle.  Below is my onCreate code.  It get Global Variable (CustomerName) which is set from previous activity.  Then, pull data from SQLLite base on the CustomerName to display data.  I think the Android VM has killed the process when user return to the activity, but I thought the process should work when the onCreate is call again.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_review);
    intialize();
    adddynamiccheckboexes();

    //Initialize
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    panelWidth = (int) ((metrics.widthPixels)*0.75);

    headerPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
    headerPanelParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) headerPanel.getLayoutParams();
    headerPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    headerPanel.setLayoutParams(headerPanelParameters);

    menuPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
    menuPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) menuPanel.getLayoutParams();
    menuPanelParameters.width = panelWidth;
    menuPanel.setLayoutParams(menuPanelParameters);

    slidingPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingPanel);
    slidingPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slidingPanel.getLayoutParams();
    slidingPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    slidingPanel.setLayoutParams(slidingPanelParameters);

    CustomerName = ((GlobalVariables) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
    //Check to see if CustName exist.  If not, go to Main screen
    CustomerName.trim();
    if (CustomerName.equals("null") || CustomerName.equals("")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }

    assessHelper = new AssessmentDBAdaptor(this);
    assessHelper.open();
    String fCustomerName = CustomerName;
    fCustomerName = fCustomerName.replaceAll("''", "'");
    fCustomerName = fCustomerName.replaceAll("'", "''");
    Cursor AssessInfo = assessHelper.fetchAssessmentByExactName(fCustomerName);
    if (AssessInfo.moveToFirst()){
        City = AssessInfo.getString(AssessInfo.getColumnIndexOrThrow("City")).toString();
        State = AssessInfo.getString(AssessInfo.getColumnIndexOrThrow("State")).toString();
        AssessDate = AssessInfo.getString(AssessInfo.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CreatedDate")).toString();
        TA_Name = AssessInfo.getString(AssessInfo.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PresentedBy")).toString();       
        CustEmail = AssessInfo.getString(AssessInfo.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Email")).toString();       
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Unable to retrieve Assessment Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    ppHelper = new DBPlantPhoto(this);
    ppHelper.open();
    fCustomerName = CustomerName;
    fCustomerName = fCustomerName.replaceAll("''", "'");
    fCustomerName = fCustomerName.replaceAll("'", "''");
    Cursor sPP = ppHelper.fetchPlantPhotoByAssessment(fCustomerName);
    if (sPP.moveToFirst()){
        FileName = sPP.getString(sPP.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FileName")).toString();
    }else{
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Unable to retrieve Plant Photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Tien
    dbBulletHelper = new DBSlideBullet(this);
    dbBulletHelper.open();

    fCustomerName = CustomerName;
    fCustomerName = fCustomerName.replaceAll("''", "'");
    fCustomerName = fCustomerName.replaceAll("'", "''");
  Cursor cAssess = dbBulletHelper.fetchSlideInfobyCateandAssess("Best Practice Summary", fCustomerName);
if (cAssess.moveToFirst()){
      //Exist
    }else{
     //Not Exist
        DBSlideBullet entry = new DBSlideBullet(ReportReview.this); //call upon database pass in context of this class
        entry.open();
        entry.CreateEntry("Best Practice Summary", "Best Practice Summary", "1", " ", "", "" ,"" ,"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", CustomerName, "" ); //Create Method in order to pass information into 
        entry.close();
    }
    cAssess = dbBulletHelper.fetchSlideInfobyCateandAssess("Current Product Overview", fCustomerName);
    if (cAssess.moveToFirst()){
      //Exist
    }else{
     //Not Exist
        DBSlideBullet entry = new DBSlideBullet(ReportReview.this); //call upon database pass in context of this class
        entry.open();
        entry.CreateEntry("Current Product Overview", "Current Product Overview", "1", " ", "", "" ,"" ,"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", CustomerName, "" ); //Create Method in order to pass information into 
        entry.close();
    }
    cAssess = dbBulletHelper.fetchSlideInfobyCateandAssess("Major Improvement Areas", fCustomerName);
    if (cAssess.moveToFirst()){
      //Exist
    }else{
     //Not Exist
        DBSlideBullet entry = new DBSlideBullet(ReportReview.this); //call upon database pass in context of this class
        entry.open();
        entry.CreateEntry("Major Improvement Areas", "Major Improvement Areas - Review", "1", " ", "", "" ,"" ,"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", CustomerName, "" ); //Create Method in order to pass information into 
        entry.close();
    }
    cAssess = dbBulletHelper.fetchSlideInfobyCateandAssess("Next Steps", fCustomerName);
    if (cAssess.moveToFirst()){
      //Exist
    }else{
     //Not Exist
        DBSlideBullet entry = new DBSlideBullet(ReportReview.this); //call upon database pass in context of this class
        entry.open();
        entry.CreateEntry("Next Steps", "Next Steps", "1", " ", "", "" ,"" ,"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", CustomerName, "" ); //Create Method in order to pass information into 
        entry.close();
    }


    Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    Storage = gotBasket.getStringArray("Storage");
    ProductApp = gotBasket.getStringArray("ProductApp");
    StandardProc = gotBasket.getStringArray("StandardProc");
    Training = gotBasket.getStringArray("Training");
    Contamination = gotBasket.getStringArray("Contamination");
    OilCondition = gotBasket.getStringArray("OilCondition");
    ReliabilityAssessment = gotBasket.getStringArray("ReliabilityAssessment");
    Planning = gotBasket.getStringArray("Planning");

    //Get User and Customer Email
    upHelper = new UserProfileDBAdaptor(this);
    upHelper.open();
    Cursor cUP = upHelper.fetchAllUserProfile();
    cUP.moveToFirst();
    UserEmail = cUP.getString(cUP.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Email")).toString();
    upHelper.close();

}
```

Comment: Please post your crash log.

Comment: We need the stack trace to find the problem but I really recommend that you read about and learn the Activity life cycle, then rebuild your app and try again.  You need to understand onCreate, onPause() and onResume() as a minimum.  Doing everything in onCreate is not a good design.

Answer (score 1):

android may throw away the complete application from memory (i.e. if memory is required).

This way the content of your variable `CustomerName` might be null and calling the trim() method can lead to nullpionterexception.

```
CustomerName = ((GlobalVariables) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
CustomerName.trim();
```